# Remove field property from object/json

Tags: json, grails

In the following code i am constructing Book.groovy json which has Author and Titles..My question is from Book.groovy how can i remove storesfield..I have tried the following and after the render i still see stores in my json response

```
 def book_custom_list(Integer max) {
    println "In book_custom_list"
    book_instance.authors.titles.remove('stores')
    book_instance.each { e ->
        println e.authors.titles

    }
    render .......
}
```

`Domain Controllers`

Book.groovy

```
class Book {
String name

static hasMany = [authors: Author]

static constraints = {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    name
}
}
```

Author.groovy

```
class Author {
String name;

static hasMany = [titles : Title]
static constraints = {
    titles cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
}
}
```

Title.groovy

```
class Title {

Stores stores
Date dateCreated


 }
```

JSON:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "test",
"authors": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sdsd",
    "titles": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "stores": {
          "id": 8,
         }
          "dateCreated": "Sep 25, 2013 12:50:42 PM",
      }
      ]
   }]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only include specific properties all the time, you would really want to use the ObjectMarshaller interface. See [this article](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/15/rendering-json-in-grails-part-3-customise-your-json-with-object-marshallers/) 
for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to customize json rendering in 2.3.  Take a look at the documention: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.RC1/guide/webServices.html#renderers